# How do I get Asp.net MVC BeginForm to add closing tag correctly?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I seem to be missing something obvious here, but cannot see what it is. 
 My problem is that the closing form tag for BeginForm is not being added to my markup. I am looping through a collection and creating a form for each item, but the forms arent closing properly. Any suggestions please?
Thanks

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>  

<% using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser","Users"))
   { %>    
    <tr>           
        <td>
            <input id="contactID" type="hidden" value="<%= item.ContactID %>" />
            <%=item.Email %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=item.Market.MarketName%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=item.ContactType.ContactTypeName%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />            
        </td>               
    </tr>
    <%} %>    
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid HTML to have a form inside a table in that way. The markup looks fine, so I'm guessing this might be your issue. You could maybe try with the form inside the `<tr>` tags. If that still doesn't work, you might need to use a div based layout.

Comment: Thanks, I manually used opening and closing form tags and had the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the markup seems right. Perhaps you can try `Html.BeginForm()` and `Html.EndForm()` instead of "using" clause.